# Facebook php sdk upload photo. How to set width and height of the photo?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook php sdk and success to upload photo but how can i set the photo size if possible at all?

```
$linkData = array(
    'source' => $fb->fileToUpload("source/to/image.png"),
    'message' => "photo message"
);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `type`? (e.g `'type' => 'small'`)?

Comment: Before or after you have uploaded the image?

Comment: no, but how do you thing about this property?

Comment: Resize it before you upload